# Detect onscroll event on custom element

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, polymer

I have written my custom element in Polymer. The element has a lot of child elements. And I would like to **detect scroll event of the element** so I can lazyload some content into it. Is it possible somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<CUSTOMELEMENT onscroll="scrollHandler">

  ...child elements here...

</CUSTOMELEMENT>
```

JS:

```
function scrollHandler(){
    console.log("scrolled!");
}
```

Comment: Oh! I found out that I was placing listener on the wrong element for the whole time :-(

Comment: @zdarsky.peter could you please share you solution

Answer (score 0):

Look if this element of polymer can be useful for you, https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scroll-threshold in any case, without an expample of the code you are using, it is dificult to know exactly what is happening, also a Jsbin could be great

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scroll event listener to your element:

```
listeners: {
    'scroll': '_userDidScrollFullElement',        
  },
```

This code will trigger the function `_userDidScrollFullElement` function on your Polymer element when the user scrolls.

If you want to be more specific and want to only trigger the function when the user scrolls a sub-element you can do the following:

```
listeners: {
    'your__element__id.scroll': '_userDidScrollSpecificElement',        
  },
```

This code will trigger the function `_userDidScrollSpecificElement` function on your Polymer element only when the user scrolls the sub-element with id `your__element__id`.

For more information on events you can check the [Polymer Events page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events).